# Agrupar filas según valor común en una columna de un dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un DataFrame como el siguiente:

```
d = {'columna_1': ['AAA45', 'FFF32', 'FFF32', 'LLL39', 'RRR35', 'RRR35'], 'columna_2': [28150502, 28150503, 28150502, 28150508, 28150510, 28150508], , 'columna_3': [10, 30, 20, 15, 60, 10]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Es posible estructurar el DataFrame de la siguiente forma, he intentado con `drop_duplicates` pero no funciona para el resultado que deseo obtener:

[image: Datframe_2]

Comment: @FJSevilla gracias por tus comentarios, editaré la pregunta con tus sugerencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que realmente buscas es agrupar por la columna `columna_1`, por lo que puedes usar `pandas.DaataFrame.groupby()`. Para generar las otras dos columnas puedes usar [agg/aggregate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

- A `columna_3` simplemente hay que aplicarle `numpy.sum`.
- A `columna_2` hay que convertirla en una lista o un array de NumPy o algún contenedor similar, una celda de un DataFrame solo puede contener un objeto, para poder agrupar los valores necesitas por tanto algún contenedor.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d = {'columna_1': ['AAA45', 'FFF32', 'FFF32', 'LLL39', 'RRR35', 'RRR35'],
     'columna_2': [28150502, 28150503, 28150502, 28150508, 28150510, 28150508],
     'columna_3': [10, 30, 20, 15, 60, 10]
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
new = (df.groupby("columna_1")
         .agg({"columna_2": np.array, "columna_3": "sum"})
         .reset_index()
         )
```

> ```
> >>> new
>   columna_1             columna_2  columna_3
> 0     AAA45              28150502         10
> 1     FFF32  [28150503, 28150502]         50
> 2     LLL39              28150508         15
> 3     RRR35  [28150510, 28150508]         70
> ```

Comment: Hola! Estoy haciendo exactamente lo que propones, pero me salta este error: "ValueError: Must produce aggregated value".

¿Qué está pasando? ¿A ti te funcionó?